# INNER JOIN and many to many tables not working

Tags: sql

I am in an intro to database class and am having trouble with my query. I am trying to return the information that would be generated for a PurchaseOrderHeader. I cannot get it to return anything.

```
Use [Sandwiches Inc]
GO

DECLARE 
@VendorID INT,
@TodaysDate DATETIME,

SELECT @VendorID = 3,
@TodaysDate = GETDATE();

SELECT
@VendorID AS Vendor,
@TodaysDate AS TDate,
V.Name,
V.Phone,
A2.Address1,
A2.Address2,
A2.AdressState,
A2.City,
A2.Zip,
A1.Address1,
A1.Address2,
A1.AdressState,
A1.City,
A1.Zip
FROM Vendor AS V
INNER JOIN VendorAddress AS VA1 on V.VendorId = VA1.VendorId
--INNER JOIN VendorAddress AS VA2 on V.VendorId = VA2.VendorId
INNER JOIN VdrAddress as A1 on VA1.VdrAddressId = A1.VdrAddressId
INNER JOIN VdrAddress AS A2 on VA1.VdrAddressId = A2.VdrAddressId
WHERE A1.Name = 'Billing' And A2.Name = 'Shipping' And V.VendorId = 3
GO
```

As it is now, it executes but does not return any columns. If I only do A1 or A2 and comment out one or the other, it works. It is when I try to do both that it fails.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information I can elaborate.

Comment: It's hard to answer this definitively as you have not described your data model. I suspect you want to use LEFT JOINs on VendorAddress and VdRAddress, in case a vendor is missing a Billing or Shipping address. Also, your commented-out bit on VendorAddress VA2 is needed, I think, in order to bring it all into one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suppose you removed the WHERE constraints to see if there is actually nothing in the greater result set?

I also assume there is relevant data in all the tables?

Where I would go from here is to remove all but one join, then slowly re-add them so I can narrow down where the issue lays.

Try that, and come back to us with more specifics.

(Ps. this is hard to do when we have no idea what is in the tables)

Comment: I just ran it and it worked. I have no idea what I changed or did differently. I added back in the commented out section, A2 inner join statement back to reference VA2 like I used to; essentially returning everything to where it was before I began troubleshooting. I commented out the WHERE clause and slowly added it back in. When I had it all in, it worked. I am going to Thank you for helping me, even though I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Update. I have no clue what is going on. My partner is trying to run my statement on his database and it is not working. It says it runs successfully, but it is not returning anything. I have no idea why it is doing the same thing for him. On his, if we comment out the where statement it returns everything. It is returning each Vendor with the address the same for both columns (expected because no where clause) but it is returning each vendor with each address twice. However, I cannot seem to add the where clause back in to get it to work. I am at a loss.

Comment: As Jeffery Kemp notes above, are you supposed to be using inner joins? You know that means there has to be data in all tables inner-joined, right?

Is there a way to check that the data in both databases is the same?

Comment: Working on the premise that your database is boned, repeat the commenty-commenty steps for individual parts within the WHERE statement on his version.

Comment: Our professor uses Inner Joins, so that is what we used. We both imported the same data from a shared Excel spreadsheet into the database. What do you mean by my database is boned?

Comment: It was just an assumption that your database wasn't quite right. No mention was ever made about your db's current state, where the data / file structure came from, and if there were any changes made to either of them.

I assumed further, that if you had two databases, and you cut/paste your code on to his - where it didn't work, then one of them was busted. I took a punt and assumed it was yours. :)

Comment: Mine works. He didn't show up for class yesterday so I'll try to fix his today if he shows up. Do you know of any reason why comment-uncomment would fix my scripts?

Comment: In short, there is no reason. There must be something else different, but I know what it's like at uni. If it works,  you move on ;) ...  Should I take the "Mine Works" to mean that you got the lecturer / tutorial teacher to sign off on the code?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that everything's fine now - glad I could be of help!

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied. Everything works; in fact, the professor is using mine as the shining example because nobody else understands SQL well enough to complete the queries (they thought the assigned homework / reading was optional). Thank you very much for your help, I wish I could have provided you with enough details to really figure out what was going on.

Comment: That's ok BicBone, happy that you got there in the end.... having said that, gifting the almighty 'tick of answerness' would be lovely ;)